# Highlight ListView item at creation time via code

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I would like to highlight the first row (0) of my ListView when I create the listView. I tried different ways (like you can see in the commented code), but nothing worked. 
It's strange because the highlight in the OnItemClickListener WORKS FINE! (It works via an xml selector).

I have this method in my fragment that it's called by onCreateView:

```
    private void createListViewAll(View rootView, int listID, String[][] textList) 
    {
        MainListAdapter bindingData = new MainListAdapter(getActivity(), textList, true);
        ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(listID);
        list.setAdapter(bindingData);
        HelperListView.getListViewSize(list);

//      list.setItemsCanFocus(true);
//        list.setItemChecked(0, true);
//        list.setSelection(0);
//        list.setSelected(true);
//        list.requestFocus();
//
//      list.setSelection(0);
//      list.setSelected(true);
//      list.getChildAt( list.getHeaderViewsCount() - list.getFirstVisiblePosition() ).setSelected(true);
//      list.getChildCount();

//      bindingData.getCount();
//      View listItem = bindingData.getView(0, null, list);
//      listItem.setActivated(true);
//      listItem.setSelected(true);
//      list.invalidate();
//      list.isItemChecked(0);

        currentView = bindingData.getView(0, null, list);


        // Click event for single list row
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) 
            {
                mItemSelected.onItemSelected(position);
                highlightView(view);
            }
        });

    }

    private void highlightView(View view) 
    {
        if (view != currentView)
        {
            if (currentView!=null)
            {
                currentView.isSelected();
                currentView.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.gradient_bg );
                currentView.setSelected(false);
                //currentView.invalidate();
            }
            view.setSelected(true);
            currentView = view;
        }
    }
```

(currentView is just a static variable)

the getView in the listAdapter:

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.titleRow = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.titleRow); 
        holder.subtitleRow = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.subtitleRow);

        vi.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{

        holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
    }

    if (position==0 && highlightFirstElement)
    {
        vi.setSelected(true);
        vi.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.gradient_bg_hover );
    }

    if (textList!=null)
    {
        holder.titleRow.setText(textList[0][position]);
        holder.subtitleRow.setText(textList[1][position]);
    }
    else
    {
        holder.titleRow.setText( arguments[idSubject.get(position)] );
        holder.subtitleRow.setText(subTitle.get(position));
    }
    return vi;
}
```

Comment: I guess if you try to do selection  via code you have to do that in the getView method of the adapter which you are binding with your listView.

Comment: I already tried to do this, it's commented:
//      View listItem = bindingData.getView(0, null, list);
//      listItem.setSelected(true);

Comment: have u tried using listview.invalidate() after making the change.

Comment: Just now. Still don't work.

Comment: I tried to extend ListView and override the method onAttachedToWindow:
 @Override
 protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
  super.onAttachedToWindow();
  setSelection(0);
  setItemChecked(0, true);
  invalidate();
 }
But didn't work.

Comment: Did you try to override setChecked to see if it goes through it ?

Comment: And if you are using a version pre honeycomb : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070905/setitemchecked-not-working-on-gingerbread

Comment: I used list.isItemChecked(0) that return true, so the item is correctly checked.
I'm using android 4.2 with the v4 support library.

Comment: I tried to call the click event too (just after the listener declaration), but doesn't work:
  View listItem = bindingData.getView(0, null, list);
  list.performItemClick(listItem, 0, 0);
The strange thing is that except this case, the item click change the item's background correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In getView method of listview's adapter class,take id of text from Layout file and apply background color to it.

for example,

```
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         View v = null;

         String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) my_ctx
                    .getSystemService(inflater);
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.layoutfile, parent, false);
                          if(position==0)
                           {

              TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
              text.setBackgroundColor(Color.ANY_COLOR);
                            }
 }
```

Comment: I edited the first post.
I tried and It nearly worked. The first item is highlighted, but when I click on another item, the first stay highlighted and the other too.

Comment: You need to create selector.xml file in your drawable folder and set background of textview as this selector file...<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

 <item android:drawable="@drawable/atext"  android:state_pressed="false" />
    <!-- Inactive tab -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btext"  android:state_pressed="true" />
    <!-- Pressed tab -->
  

</selector>

Comment: Like you can read in the first post, I already have a selector, but it don't work good.